# Wifi network - Bad signal troubleshooting

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I am facing huge wifi issues since some months and have tried different solutions that do not seem to work. I'll give you a little history before giving some data.

My house was before connected to internet through ADSL technology. Being in Belgium, I was on the Proximus network with a BBox2. The speed was rather low compared to some other places that were better deserved. Despite that, all house was deserved with a strong signal even far in the street. Speed was bad, but signal was quite strong. However, some years ago, we finally got the VDSL technology with improved download and upload speeds.

Since some months, however, the signal is getting really bad in all the house. I did a test in all the different rooms to get the signal strength:

- Office: -49 dBm (just next to the router)
- Kitchen: -80 dBm (room next to the office)
- Livingroom: -79 dBm (room also close to the office)
- Diningroom: -86 dBm (a bit more far but the room is still quite close)
- Upstair rooms: ranges from -70 to -85 dBm depending on the location.

All tests have been realized on a 2.4 Ghz network (the 5 has not a range that is sufficient for some rooms). I tried manually selecting the best channel using a scan utility on my MacBook Pro. However, there are not much networks around (my Mac finds only 3 including my 2.4 and 5). It was in auto and I tried the best from the scan utility which are the 6 and 11 channels, no change.

When I achieve a speediest from my livingroom, I get these numbers on both wifis:

- 2.4: -79 dBm; 0.7 Mbps (down); 6 Mbps (up)
- 5.0: -80 dBm; 29 Mbps (down); 7.8 Mbps (up)
  One could say I could only use the 5 Ghz wifi but I can easily lose the signal in many rooms and it's quite annoying.

My 2.4 wifi is set on 802.11 gn mode. I can select the g mode but it does not improve the situation. The 5 is on ac mode.

I had a BBox3 router and I changed for a Bbox3x+ router as I thought the router was the problem. But the problem persists.

Comment: How large is your house and have you tried moving the router to a more central location? Most households solve these kinds of issues by adding more Access Points or Wifi extenders at strategic locations. For example powerline Wifi devices can be effective.

Comment: Quite difficult to move the router in that room. Maybe I could only try to use a CPL somewhere else in the house. It's however weird to me that my old wifi was quite excellent but the new one sucks as much. The new router is supposed to be more performant so there's no reason for this wifi to have such weak signal even in the closest room.